# Trying to Cache HttpClient Response but getting 'HttpResponse<Blob>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Response'

Tags: angular, caching, httpclient, httpresponse, cachestorage

So, basically in my Angular project I'm trying to cache an HttpClient's request and response using the [Cache API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache) through the following line of code:

```
from(caches.open(this.getCacheName(this.chatAttachmentsCache)))
  .pipe(map(cache => {
    cache.put(request, response);
  }));
```

The request argument is the request's URL and the response argument is the request's response.

I pass the HttpResponse object, that I get from the successful HttpClient GET request, to the cache.put call as the response. However, I keep getting this error in the text editor.

```
Argument of type 'HttpResponse<Blob>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Response'.
  Type 'HttpResponse<Blob>' is missing the following properties from type 'Response': redirected, trailer, bodyUsed, arrayBuffer, and 4 more
```

I obtain the HttpResponse object from the following line of code:

```
    return this.httpClient.get(url, { responseType: "blob", observe: "response" });
```

I don't really know how to resolve this issue. Does this mean I cannot use the caches API with HttpClient in Angular? Or is there some workaround to handle such an issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to resolve this issue.

For anyone experiencing the same issue. I created a new Response object through the constructor and passed the body, status and status text from the HttpResponse to it as per the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/Response). Here is an example:

```
const responseAsResponseType = new Response(response.body, {
  "status": response.status,
  "statusText": response.statusText,
});
```